# Why do PyMC3 and Tensorflow need the double naming of objects?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pymc

When declaring objects in PyMC3, Tensorflow and few other packages, we need to repeat the name of the object, e.g.

```
alpha = pymc.Normal('alpha', mu=0, tau=.01)
```

Why exactly this is needed? Why couldn't it be simplified to something like

```
alpha = pymc.Normal(mu=0, tau=.01)
```

or

```
pymc.Normal('alpha', mu=0, tau=.01)
```

This seems to be a strange interface decision at first sight. Is this a matter of convention, or a technological problem?

Answer (score 1):

names in `tensorflow/pymc` is different from an variable identifier.

example:

`beta = pymc.Normal('alpha', mu=0, tau=.01)` is perfectly valid (although confusing)

Here the name `beta` is for human reference, we can call it `a, b, c` also. And the name 'alpha' is used as an internal name which will be used in logging and debugging.

What you are suggesting `alpha = pymc.Normal(mu=0, tau=.01)` about taking the name `alpha` and using this as a default internal name, it's possible but has some issues.

In different name spaces the variable name alpha might get reused:

For example:

```
values = []
For i in range(10):
    alpha = pymc.Normal(mu=0, tau=.01)
    values.append(alpha)
    # in this case all values will be logged as alpha which will be confusing to debug.
```

A simpler solution:

```
values = []
For i in range(10):
    alpha = pymc.Normal('alpha{}'.format(i), mu=0, tau=.01)
    values.append(alpha)
    # in this case values will be logged as alpha_<i> which will not be so confusing to debug.
```

PS: example is a simplified one only for reference

Comment: But assigning to vector seems to be simple and flexible: alpha[i] = pymc.Normal(0, 1)

Comment: Think of it in terms of different methods also, or what if you call the same method twice, Ideally it's better to have control over what get's logged. Better control to the developers.